# How to initialize keycloak with locale in i18n Angular app?

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

We use keycloak [https://www.keycloak.org/] server for user authentication in our Angular 6 app. We also use this wrapper library https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular to interact with the underneath JavaScript keycloak Adapter and initialization.

Keycloak is the first thing in the app that gets initialized (from provided configuration) via Angular's APP_INITIALIZER provider.

Since we use Angular with internationalization and ahead of time compilation, we have deployed our apps like this:

```
   https://my-site/en
   https://my-site/fr
```

I want to render login page in respective locale when navigated. If navigated to my-site/fr keycloak login page should render in french and so on. But there is no way to provide locale in keyclaok config while app initialization.

PS: Keycloak realm is already configured to allow internationalization and user can change language from login page. I know keycloak adapter's login method takes "locale" param but I can only access that after app has been initialized.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For those facing a similar problem, the resolution may be found at [How to initialize keycloak with locale in i18n Angular app](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/72).

Comment: Perfect. I totally forgot to update my question here. Thanks for doing it. @mauriciovigolo

Comment: I should thank you, @h3ll0w0rld, for sharing your resolution to this problem!